# Merging with git after deleting some files

Tags: git

I have two branches that I want to merge, say `master` and `test`. When working on my `test` branch I deleted some files (for no special reason) which I expected to be a conflict when merging back the branches; but it doesn't. The files are simply deleted by git. And I get why: when pulling the branch git is telling me that these files are in `delete mode`, so it kind of makes sense. I also noticed that some old files (already not present on the project) are also on `delete mode`. Is there a way that I can make that branch completely ignore all `delete mode` files so they can be added by the other branch?

Answer (score 0):

If you get those files shown as "in delete mode" then you did not properly commit the delete action.
What you need to do is

```
$ git add -A # add all deleting to the index
$ git commit -am 'deleted files' # commit them
```

=> now those files should be gone clean from your branch's index.